# How to strip a pretrained network and add some layers to it using pytorch lightning?

Tags: pytorch, transfer-learning, pytorch-lightning

I am trying to use transfer learning for an image segmentation task, and my plan is to use the first few layers of a pretrained model (VGG16 for example) as an encoder and then will add my own decoder.

So, I can load the model and see the structure by printing it:

```
model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.6.0', 'resnet18', pretrained=True)
print(model)
```

I get like this:

```
ResNet(
  (conv1): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2), padding=(3, 3), bias=False)
  (bn1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
  (maxpool): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  (layer1): Sequential(
    (0): BasicBlock(
      (conv1): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    )
    (1): BasicBlock(
      (conv1): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    )
  )
  .....
  .....
  .....
```

I can also access the specific layers with `model.layer3` for example. Now, I am struggling with certain things.

1. How to cut the model and take every module from the beginning to the end of any layer (model.layer3 for example)?
2. How to `freeze` only this stripped part, and keep the newly added modules available for training?

Answer (score 2):

For 1): Initialize the ResNet in your `LightningModule` and slice it until the part that you need. Then add your own head after that, and define `forward` in the order that you need. See this example, based on the [transfer learning docs](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/transfer_learning.html#example-imagenet-computer-vision):

```py
import torchvision.models as models

class ImagenetTransferLearning(LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # init a pretrained resnet
        backbone_tmp = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
        num_filters = backbone_tmp.fc.in_features
        layers = list(backbone_tmp.children())[:-1]
        self.backbone = nn.Sequential(*layers)

        # use the pretrained model to classify cifar-10 (10 image classes)
        num_target_classes = 10
        self.classifier = nn.Linear(num_filters, num_target_classes)
```

For 2): Pass a  `BackboneFinetuning` [callback](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extensions/generated/pytorch_lightning.callbacks.BackboneFinetuning.html?highlight=Backbonefinetuning) to your `trainer`. This requires that your `LightningModule` has a `self.backbone` attribute containing the modules that you want to be frozen, as shown on the snippet above. You can also use the `BaseFinetuning` [callback](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extensions/generated/pytorch_lightning.callbacks.BaseFinetuning.html#pytorch_lightning.callbacks.BaseFinetuning) if you need different freeze-unfreeze behavior.

```py
from pytorch_lightning import Trainer
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import BackboneFinetuning
multiplicative = lambda epoch: 1.5
backbone_finetuning = BackboneFinetuning(200, multiplicative)
trainer = Trainer(callbacks=[backbone_finetuning])
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is true for any child module of `model`, but I will answer your question with `model.layer3` here:

1. `model.layer3` will give you the `nn.Module` associated with layer n°3 of your model. You can call it directly as you would with `model`

   ```
   >>> z = model.layer3(torch.rand(16, 128, 10, 10))
   >>> z.shape
   torch.Size([16, 256, 5, 5])
   ```
2. To *freeze* the model:

   - you could put the layer in *eval* mode which disables dropouts and makes BN layers use statistics learning during training. This is done with `model.layer3.eval()`
   - you must disable training on that layer by toggling the `requires_grad` flag: `model.layer3.requires_grad_(False)`, this will affect all child parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can freeze the layers with:

```
pretrained_model.freeze()
```

https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pytorch_lightning.core.lightning.html?highlight=Freeze#pytorch_lightning.core.lightning.LightningModule.freeze